# Why type is not safe in template class?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have encountered a strange error relating to template class in C++. The codes run OK most of the time, but in one occasion it failed. The following is simplified codes:

```
template <class T>
class Class1
{
    ...
    T *func();
    ...
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>
T *Class1<T>::func(...)
{
    ...
    string name = typeid(T).name();
    T *ptr = a_queue.front(); // a_queue is of type "queue<T *>"
    ptr->some_func(); // failed
    ...
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

Class1<Class2> class1;
class1.func();
```

Suppose `Class1` is specialized with `T` is `Class2` and `Class3` respectively. In `Class1<Class2>::func`, `ptr` is declared as `Class3` pointer in that occasion! So the type is not safe in template class?

Any idea? Thanks!

Edit:

I have added `string name = typeid(T).name()`, then `T` will be correct type (`Class2`), but when call the member function `some_func` of `Class2`, there is a error:

```
cannot access memory address at 0x10
```

---

**[Solved] Final edit 2011/11/09:**

I have found the problem, it is not related to template class, but caused by deleting the wrong pointer, which is not newed in the same function with `delete` and has been pushed into the queue!

Comment: Do you mean `Class1` is specialized? You can't specialize `T` -- it is just a type. In `Class1<Class2>`, `T` is `Class2`...when you get a "strange error," you should post that error, because a C++ compiler can print any number of strange errors.

Comment: Yes, `Class1` is specialized. I expect `T` in `Class1<Class2>` should be `Class2`, but it is `Class3` in my case. There is no directly relating error output, and my codes are pretty huge, so I do not have any idea how to put the errors.

Comment: Do you allocate memory for `ptr` by `new`? Are you casting the output of `func()` to another type? **The question is very ambiguous.**

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question! Because it surprises me deeply. I don't allocate memory for `ptr`, just assign an address of a `Class2` object in a queue to it as `T *ptr = a_queue.front()`.

Comment: @LiDong, you need to come up with a complete, *minimal* code snippet that would reproduce the problem that you're having. You should then explain what output you get and what output you expect.

Comment: @avakar, I am afraid that it would be impossible to extract the minimal problematic codes from my project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can we see the specialization code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cannot access memory address at 0x10

That is equivalent to a NULL pointer reference.  The compiler started with some `T *ptr = 0` and tried to find a member (or vtable) of `T` at offset 0x10 so it looked at memory `0 + 0x10`.  So I don't think your problem is a matter of template types but of `a_queue.front()` containing NULL.

Comment: Your answer seems the right direction to solve this weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a template *function*.  Did you template *both* the class *and* the function?

```
template <typename T>
class Class1
{
    template <typename U>
    U *::func(... some argument of U...)
};
```

That would allow you to call `Class1<Class2>::func(...some arg Class3...)` and get `func<Class3>` inside `Class1<Class2>`.

Comment: Yes, I have templated both `Class1` and its method `func` with `T`.